# React Native Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, react-native

I am trying to view JSON data downloaded but receiving Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. The error code is not helping at all. If I access the JSON using browser, I don't see a problem. It somehow giving error during parsing. Can someone give any suggestions ?

```
export default class CategoryScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            datasource: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('http://xhunterx.ezyro.com/a-cnn.json')
            .then((response) => response.json() )
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.movies,
                })
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        } else {

            let news = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
                return <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>{val.title}</Text>
                </View>
            });

            return (       
 
                <View>
                    {news}
            </View>
            );
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this line

```
dataSource: responseJson.movies
```

You are having an array directly in `responseJson`, not inside `movies`. Try with

```
dataSource: responseJson
```

Comment: i changed it to responseJson but it is still not working. Still getting the same error. Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0